# Access Violation on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++

I have a problem in my C++ code, look at this function:

```
void insere(titem x){
    tlista *aux;
    aux = (tlista*)malloc(sizeof(tlista));
    aux->item = x;
    ultimo->prox = aux;
    ultimo = ultimo->prox;
    aux->prox = NULL;
}
```

When the line: `aux->item = x;` is performed, Visual Studio says:

> Unhandled exception at 0x53eacafa (msvcr100d.dll) in TP6.exe:

Look at my struct titem:

```
 struct titem {
      int prioridade;
      string nome;
      int freq;
 };
```

In Dev-C++ the code works ok! What might case the problem and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `malloc` to allocate an memory for an object. That will allocate the memory, but it will not initialize the object. That's a problem for the non-POD members, for example `aux->item.nome`.

Instead of using malloc you need to use `new`.

```
tlista *aux = new tlista;
```

When you are done with the struct, use `delete` to dispose of it.

```
delete aux;
```

Since you are using C++ you should forget all about `malloc` and `free`. Heap allocations are performed with `new` and `delete` in C++.

Comment: Thank YOU David! I am Brazilian and I was amazed at the speed of you! You are fantastic!

Comment: @Marcony Felipe - To answer your question in 1 minute he was using a crystal ball seeing your text as you were printing it )